# what i'm doing wrong here? the code crashes

Tags: javascript

I really can't find out what i'm doing wrong!

```js
    setInterval(function() {
        var time = document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML;
        var x = time * 1000 - 400;
        setTimeout(function() {

            
                var x2 = document.getElementById("2x-total").innerHTML;
                var x3 = document.getElementById("3x-total").innerHTML;
                if (x2 < 2 * x3) {
                    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                    var run = document.getElementById("btn2x");
                    run.dispatchEvent(evt);
                }
            
        }, x);

    }, 7000);


function x2a() {
    document.getElementById("x2p").innerHTML = x2;
}

function x3a() {
    document.getElementById("x3p").innerHTML = x3;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">01.14</div>

<button id="btn2x" onclick="x2a()" style="display: block;">2x</button>
<button id="btn3x" onclick="x3a()" style="display: block;">3x</button>
<span id="2x-total">12000</span>
<span id="3x-total">12000</span>
<p id="x2p"></p>
<p id="x3p"></p>
```

the code should run in a loop, first wait 7 seconds and than run the script,the script should search the timer value and wait till there are just 400 miliseconds and press on the correct button, but it crashes, what could I do?

Comment: `while (1)`  creates an infinite loop. Within that loop you are setting up recurring timers. Of course this will crash the browser. `setInterval()` is already going to run its callback ***every*** 7000 millseconds, so what's the purpose of the loop?

Comment: `first wait 7 seconds`  That's not a setInterval it's a setTimeout.

Comment: `document.getElementById("x2p").innerHTML = x2;`  x2 here is out of scope, x2 here will not be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're declaring your `x2` and `x3` variables inside of the `setInterval` anonymous method. Try this:

```
var x2;
var x3;
setInterval(function() {
    var time = document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML;
    var x = time * 1000 - 400;
    setTimeout(function() {


            x2 = document.getElementById("2x-total").innerHTML;
            x3 = document.getElementById("3x-total").innerHTML;
            if (x2 < 2 * x3) {
                var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                var run = document.getElementById("btn2x");
                run.dispatchEvent(evt);
            }

    }, x);

}, 7000);


function x2a() {
    document.getElementById("x2p").innerHTML = x2;
}

function x3a() {
    document.getElementById("x3p").innerHTML = x3;
}
```

Comment: This is odd, the OP has even supplied a Snippet, and then you have de-snippet'ed it.. :)

Comment: Yeah I'm kinda new to snippets, not sure how to fix that D:

Comment: @DrRoach You can click "Copy snippet to answer".

Comment: Trying to do that I'm getting an incorrect code formatting error :S Just going to leave as is for now but promise to do better in the future.. Seriously though, my bad

Comment: yeah ths solved it

Comment: @LordofLogic glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

First remove while(1) {} loop.

Comment: done, now what ,it's still doesn't work! any idea?

Comment: @LordofLogic If you press the "Run code snippet" button and try it, it pretty much tells you what is wrong.

Comment: @LordofLogic Start by being more concise. What does "still doesn't work" mean? Is it still crashing? Are you getting an error?